# how python works for single line multiple assignments and multiple line single assignments

Tags: python-3.x, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
curr = head
prev = None
while curr:
    curr.next = prev
    prev = curr
    curr = curr.next
return prev
```

when I run this list is not reversing just returning a single node

```
prev, curr = None, head
while curr:
    curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
return prev
```

when I run this it works perfectly how these two works could someone explain?

Comment: The second code updates all values together with no intermediate steps. In the top code, try storing the values in temporary variables then do the updates.Specifically, you are setting `cur.next` in the first line then using it to set `curr`

Comment: thanks brother I got it now

Answer (score 0):

(moving comment to answer)

The second code updates all values together with no intermediate steps. Specifically, you are setting `curr.next` in the first line then using it to set `curr`.

In the top code, try storing `curr.next` in a temporary variable then do the updates to generate the same result.

```
curr = head
prev = None
while curr:
    cnext = curr.next
    curr.next = prev
    prev = curr
    curr = cnext
return prev
```